# Azure Storage Emulator Connection string for Azure Function Queue Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-emulator

[image: Code]

[image: error]

What should be the connection string?

i used http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1

got almost the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sample of [function.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#example-trigger-and-binding)

Value of connection should be the name of app setting in local.settings.json, like

```
"connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
```

And in local.settings.json, set the name&value pair.

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
```